# getting part of a bitmap image in Visual basic express 2010

Tags: vb.net

What would be the code needed to crop (get images from within a picture)?

Comment: This is not the best way to answer a question, but you are new and trying your level best. Perhaps you should re-format the question a bit, such that the ideas are clearer and, potentially, more helpful to others. I am writing this comment as a summary of all what we discussed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works by creating a smaller rectangle with the desired dimensions from the (rectangular) input image and loading it into a `PictureBox` (`PictureBox1`). This can be useful for card game software.

```
Private Function CropBitmap(ByRef bmp As Bitmap, ByVal cropX As Integer, ByVal cropY As Integer, ByVal cropWidth As Integer, ByVal cropHeight As Integer) As Bitmap 
    Dim rect As New Rectangle(cropX, cropY, cropWidth, cropHeight) 
    Dim cropped As Bitmap = bmp.Clone(rect, bmp.PixelFormat) 
    Return cropped 
End Function  
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load 
    Dim FN = "full path of the image file"
    Dim bmp As Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.FromFile(FN) 
    PictureBox1.Image = CropBitmap(bmp, 4, 4, 13, 16) 
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 For the effort you put to adapt yourself to this site.